# Magento - adding reviews to product page in block. cant get form to load

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add reviews and the form to my product page in magento ... NOT in tabs. 
if i use 
               getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
and add the following code to my local.xml it works.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
    <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" before="product.info.tags" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
    <!-- <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" /> -->
    <block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
    <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
    <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before">
    <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
    </block>
    </block>
    </block>
    </block> 
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But, also tags are also called by additional_data and then they show up before the reviews and not after. And as far as i can tell, i cant use BEFORE/AFTER with this block type?

so i thought i could create a separate block that will call the reviews called "reviews".
and place it above "additional_data".

i changed my code to the following in local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info">
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="reviews" before="product.info.tags" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<!-- <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" /> -->
<block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml">
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before">
<action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
</block>
</block>
</block>
</block> 
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

but i cant get the form to show up. i tried adding a template call to the form but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.
open: review.xml, in your “layout” directory.

Find following section:

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
```

Add the following inside this block:

```
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data_review" template="review/product/view/reviews-in-tab.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
</block>
```

So your final result should be as...

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data_review" template="review/product/view/reviews-in-tab.phtml">
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Now clear your cache and check output.